# Where to write ATs/UATs in JIRA?

Tags: tools

In JIRA, if I create a high level user story, where do I put the AT(s)?

If I put the ATs into the user story, say as text "AT: must do blah blah", then the user story gets split into sub tasks for the developers to work on, do the ATs need to be moved/repeated into each sub task or is it acceptable to have developers reference the parent user story for ATs when working on tickets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of JIRA, I would put the AT descriptions into a gherkin form and create cucumber features and scenarios so that they can be used by testers and developers creating test cases.

First, if you have the description in an issue tracking system, you'll have to move them around and there won't be a good place anywhere. Second, you won't be able to automate and reuse them later.

Comment: Thanks Zsolt!

QA I learned is one of the most important parts of web dev projects, but I'm often relying on employees or peers to introduce me to new technologies - and now Stack Exchange :)

I will do some research now into how to implement BDD principles (I think I was mostly before, but didn't know what they were called).

A little unsure still of whether I'll move the ATs out of JIRA completely, as the developers will be looking at the initial issue/story/bug and creating dev sub tasks from those. Convenient for me and Product Owner to be able to see readable Gherkin code there...